# How to edit and save a PDF in Firefox 107 with JavaScript?

Tags: pdf, firefox

With the latest version of Firefox (107) it is now possible to edit and sign PDF documents within the browser preview window.

[image]

But how can I upload an updated version of such a PDF file back into my Web Application?
Is there any kind of JavaScript API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There is much overlap between PDF web editing browsers and Browser editing PDFs

the data is pulled down locally and the binary application edits the data however for a PDF, that then requires a local save as a new combined PDF. here we can see a visual reminder.

[image]

In Firefox or Chrome there are slight differences but the core need is to resave the PDF as a clients local file.

Chrome has inking
[image]

And Firefox uses a slightly different overlay but again the conjoined local data  must be first saved as a new PDF.

either by print
[image] or the top right Save (again) AS

[image]

Thus to achieve your goal you need to **ask the annotator user** to upload their masterpiece. However you cannot easily do that in the sandboxed page (with work frame) it needs to be after a user signal such as press button here to upload where-ever ***IF*** you were able or bothered to save as a new pdf.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there any javaScript API within Firefox I can use to avoid the user have to do this and instead I transfer the file to a secure server for him?